# the routing is working locally but not online(vercel)

Tags: reactjs, vercel

I have a react website that when going throug routes workes fine but if you refresh vercel show not found(eg user in the home"/" could go to "/form" which works but if he reloads 404 error occurs) I think this is an issue because of react spa or something iam not pretty sure (note I removed some code for simplicty
another example if a user would click on website.com/about-us he would have 404 error but if he goes to "/" and click the  it works

```
import React from "react";  
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"; 
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom"; 
import Navbar from './components/Navbar' 
import Footer from "./components/Footer";  
import { UserAuthContextProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";  
import AboutUs from "./routes/AboutUs";
import Form from "./routes/Form";
import App from "./routes/App"; 
import AdminSignIn from "./routes/AdminSignIn";
import ErrorPage from './routes/ErrorPage'
import Admin from "./routes/Admin";
import FolderPicker from "./components/FolderPicker";
import { GSSubjectOptions,LSSubjectOptions,LHSubjectOptions,ESSubjectOptions,typeApplcation } from './Subjects/subjects';
import FilePicker from "./components/FilePicker"; 
import './index.css'
import {collection, addDoc, setDoc,doc , getDocs,getDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { db } from './firebase'; 
import Protected from "./components/Protacted";
let AceppetedFiles=[]
async function getMarker(){
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "fileData"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { 
    if(doc.data()&&doc.data().STATUS === 'ACCEPTED'){
        AceppetedFiles.push(doc.data()) 
    }
    
});
}
getMarker()   
console.log(AceppetedFiles) 
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />, 
    errorElement:<ErrorPage />,
  },
  {
    path: "about-us/",
    element: <AboutUs /> ,
  }, 
  {
    path: "/form",
    element: <Form /> ,
  }, 
  {
    path: "/AdminSignIn",
    element: <AdminSignIn /> ,
  }, 
  {
    path: "/Admin",
    element:
    <Protected>
       <Admin />
    </Protected>
     ,
  }, 
  {
    path: "/ES",
    element: <FolderPicker subjects={ESSubjectOptions} /> ,
  }, 
 
  {
    path: "/LS",
    element: <FolderPicker subjects={LSSubjectOptions} /> ,
  }, 
  {
    path: "/LH",
    element: <FolderPicker subjects={LHSubjectOptions} /> ,
  }, 
  {
    path: "/GS",
    element: <FolderPicker subjects={GSSubjectOptions} /> ,
  },  
 

  {
    path: "/GS",
    element: <FolderPicker subjects={GSSubjectOptions} /> ,
  },  
{
  path:'/*',
  element: <div>reRoute</div> , 
}
]);  
console.log(GSSubjectOptions)
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render( 
    <UserAuthContextProvider>   
    <RouterProvider router={router} />  
    </UserAuthContextProvider> 
);
```

Comment: Have you followed the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#vercel) for Vercel to configure the server to return the correct page for each request? The basic gist is that the server/hosting service should be configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app.

Comment: I use vite so Iam not pretty sure if it is the same thing

Comment: It's just general deployment documentation not specific to CRA or vite if that is what you use. Each server/hosting service is different and has different requirements/configurations/etc.